# Stacked area chart in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to create a graph like: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html in D3.js or this kind of stacked area chart is inclusive for NVD3? Does any one know any related example in D3.js,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stacked area chart you are referring to is part of NVD3. See [the source code](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html#source_code) below the chart.

Another example which does not need NVD3 but is less interactive can be [found here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211). This one only requires d3.js. There is also a [nice gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) of d3.js examples including source code.